# How to read an Excel file from a folder without specifying the filename?

Tags: r

Is there a way to read an Excel file into R directly from a folder without having to specify the filename?
I'm using the readxl library and I have only 1 file in the folder, but the file's name changes monthly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in other answers, this can be solved using the [`dir`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html) function.

Assuming the variable `path` contains the path of the directory in which the XLSX file is located, then the following will give you the full path to the file:

```r
file_path = dir(path, pattern = '\\.xlsx$', full.names = TRUE)
```

Note that `pattern` uses [regular expressions](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html#matching-patterns-with-regular-expressions) rather than glob format! Using the glob pattern `*.xlsx` might appear to work but it’s incorrect, only works by accident, and will also match other file names.

Answer (score 2):

The computer need to have the path anyway BUT you can get it without giving if you are absolutly sure that this is the only one file in your folder

see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html
to learn more about how to open a directory and getting filename inside.

If this isn't the only file but this is the only excel file you while have to get the extension of each file and do some parsing to take a decision of wich file you want to open

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file is located inside a folder called `myFolder` located in disk `E:\\`

```r
library(readxl)

folderPath <- "E://myFolder"
fileName <- grep(".xlsx", dir(folderPath), value = TRUE)
filePath <- paste(folderPath, fileName, sep = "//")
df <- read_xlsx(filePath)
```

This code will get the name of your xlsx file inside `folderPath` each time you run it and then you can import it with `readxl::read_xlsx`. I assume there is only one xlsx file inside the folder.

Comment: There’s no need for `grep`: `dir` has a `pattern` argument. There’s also no need for the `paste` step: `dir` has a `full.names` argument. Note also that instead of paste you should generally use `file.path`, and using a double slash is wrong (though it happens to work): a single slash is sufficient.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph- Can you please explain how exactly you would write it?

Comment: @jennyro See my own answer.